# Three.js Enemy Moves towards player

Tags: javascript, geometry, three.js

In three.js I have a space ship at xyz,   And id like it to fly towards a mesh object of a planet at xyz.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Needs to travel in a straight line, at a speed constant towards the planet.

Answer (score 1):

```
 updateFcts.push(function(delta, now){

    if (shipArr[0]===undefined){
}else{  

       //create two vector objects
var xd = new THREE.Vector3(marsMesh.position.x,marsMesh.position.y,marsMesh.position.z);
var yd = new THREE.Vector3(shipArr[0].position.x,shipArr[0].position.y,shipArr[0].position.z);
//find the distance / hypotnuse to the xyz location
var dicks = shipArr[0].position.distanceTo(marsMesh.position);

 var subvec = new THREE.Vector3();
     subvec = subvec.subVectors(xd,yd);
     //sub subtrac the 3 vectors.
   var hypotenuse = dicks;
     console.log(hypotenuse);
   //1.5 stops it at 1.5 distance from the target planet


       if(hypotenuse > 1.5){
        //console.log(hypotenuse);

    shipArr[0].position.y += .0001*200*(subvec.y/hypotenuse);
    shipArr[0].position.x += .0001*200*(subvec.x/hypotenuse);
    shipArr[0].position.z += .0001*200*(subvec.z/hypotenuse);
    }else{
    //within fire range
    alert ("FIIIIIRE");

    }


}

})
```

I tried tween.js and was unhappy so i coded a function myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/sole/tween.js which is focused on that.

A very basic example http://jsfiddle.net/qASPe (square will fly towards sphere after 5s) with mainly this code:

```
new TWEEN.Tween(ship.position)
    .to(planet.position, 700) // destination, duration 
    .start();
```

Later, you might want to use a THREE.Curve, or other Path mechanism, as a "flying" path like here http://jsfiddle.net/aevdJ/12

```
// create a path
var path = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
    ship.position,
    // some other points maybe? representing your landing/takeoff trajectory
    planet.position
]);

new TWEEN.Tween({ distance:0 })
    .to({ distance:1 }, 3000) // destination, duration 
    .onUpdate(function(){
        var pathPosition = path.getPointAt(this.distance);
        ship.position.set(pathPosition.x, pathPosition.y, pathPosition.z);
    })
    .start();
```

In all cases, do not forget to add this line in your update function

```
TWEEN.update();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried tween.js but i couldn't for the life of me figure out how to pause cancel update or alter the tween. seemed like once it was set it was set in stone.